# javascript not rendering styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dont know why this code is not working!

html, css, javascript is not working in same html page

plz help I cant figure out this.. is it problem on browser or my code is wrong
every thing seems to be fine...

```js
function render() {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    alert('hello');
    var overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
    var alert = document.getElementsByClassName('alertbox');
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
    overlay.style.background = 'blue';
    overlay.style.height = winH + 'px';
    overlay.style.width = winW + 'px';
    overlay.style.border = '10px solid black';
    
}
```

```css
.overlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.alertbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: magenta;
    z-index: 10; 
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body> 
 <h3>Custom Alert Box Demo</h3>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('hello world')">render overlay</button>
<button type="button" onclick="render()">render overlay</button>

<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="alertbox">
 <div class="head"></div>
 <div class="body"></div>
 <div class="foot"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/4yc1eeL8/)

Your script has two errors. Please replace your script with the below given one

```
function render() {
  var winW = window.innerWidth;
  var winH = window.innerHeight;
  var overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0];
  var alert = document.getElementsByClassName('alertbox')[0];
  overlay.style.display = 'block';
  overlay.style.background = 'blue';
  overlay.style.height = winH + 'px';
  overlay.style.width = winW + 'px';
  overlay.style.border = '10px solid black';
}
```

First error was in the line,

```
alert('hello');
```

because, you have a variable with name `alert` in your script and thus you will get an error `alert is not a function` in your console. If you want the alert to be shown, then you should rename your variable with name `alert` to some other name, may be for eg, rename it to `alert1`. Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/4yc1eeL8/1/).

Second error was in the line

```
var overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
```

because `document.getElementsByClassName()` always returns an array.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> `getElementsByClassName()` Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of
>   the given class names. When called on the document object, the
>   complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also
>   call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only
>   elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the
>   given class names.

What I have done in the fiddle is that, I've selected the first element with the class name `overlay` using the index position `0`. Similarly for the class `alertbox`.